# How to use achemso bibliography style without achemso package?

Tags: achemso

I tried to use the [`achemso`](http://ctan.org/pkg/achemso) bibliography style for a document which is not an article I want to submit to a journal. Thus I do not use the `achemso` class neither the `achemso` package.

It works but references are not numbered. How can I change this or does it exist a standard bib style which looks like `achemso`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of the `achemso` package is recommended when using the `achemso` bibliography style as it provides a convenient interface to alter the control values used by the style. However, it's perfectly possible to use the bibliography style without the package. To do that, the key thing to bear in mind is that it's a numbered `natbib` style, and so you should be loading the `natbib` package with the `numbers` option

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Abernethy2003,
  author = {Colin D. Abernethy and Gareth M. Codd and Mark D. Spicer
    and Michelle K. Taylor},
  title = {{A} highly stable {N}-heterocyclic carbene complex of
    trichloro-oxo-vanadium(\textsc{v}) displaying novel
    {C}l---{C}(carbene) bonding interactions},
  journal = {{J}. {A}m. {C}hem. {S}oc.},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {125},
  pages = {1128--1129},
  number = {5},
  doi = {10.1021/ja0276321},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\begin{document}
Text\cite{Abernethy2003}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

If you want to be able to control the output of the bibliography, for example setting whether or not article titles are included, then you need to have a special 'control' database entry, and to cite this. That can be achieved in basically the same way the package works:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Abernethy2003,
  author = {Colin D. Abernethy and Gareth M. Codd and Mark D. Spicer
    and Michelle K. Taylor},
  title = {{A} highly stable {N}-heterocyclic carbene complex of
    trichloro-oxo-vanadium(\textsc{v}) displaying novel
    {C}l---{C}(carbene) bonding interactions},
  journal = {{J}. {A}m. {C}hem. {S}oc.},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {125},
  pages = {1128--1129},
  number = {5},
  doi = {10.1021/ja0276321},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-control.bib}
@Control{achemso-control,
  ctrl-article-title  = "no",
  ctrl-chapter-title  = "no",
  ctrl-etal-number    = "15",
  ctrl-etal-firstonly = "yes",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{achemso-control}}
\begin{document}
Text\cite{Abernethy2003}
\bibliography{\jobname,\jobname-control}
\end{document}
```

or of course you can add the control entry to your main `.bib` file. Hopefully the control entries are clear enough.

Comment: Nice ! It works perfectly. I did not know the `@control` facilities it is really helpful. I read the sentence you copy from the manual (your manual ;) ) but I have to say that these examples are really clearer. I just have this warning : `Package natbib Warning: Citation 'achemso-control' undefined on input line`. Why do you add this line in the source ? `\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{achemso-control}}`.

Comment: @Ger No quite sure about the warning: will have to look into it. You need `\AtBeginDocument` as citations are written to the `.aux` file, and that is cleared at the start of the document. You could just add `\nocite{achemso-control}` after `\begin{document}`, but as it's not really part of the document I think it's 'better style' to set this in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

It is much more straightforward just to put after `documentclass` command the following line:

```
\documentclass[journal=langmuir,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle=true}
```

This would just introduce title in the references.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The `achemso` class is _really_ not suitable for use other than for journal submission as there are several internal assumptions about the base class and package loading. It is _much_ better to use the `achemso` package for general documents.