# change bibliography output with different files for each chapter

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, achemso

I am writing my thesis in pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX using achemso bibliography style, and I am using a root file with different files and bib for each chapter.  I am trying to adjust the output of the bibiliography (i.e. add the title, remove et al and list all authors, break up a url, etc).  I have tried a number of different things, including trying to add a control sequence (described here: [How to use achemso bibliography style without achemso package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69146/how-to-use-achemso-bibliography-style-without-achemso-package)).  I'm not sure if I'm not putting things in the right place, but nothing is working.  Help?
Main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{thesis}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite} 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.} 
\makeatother 
\renewcommand\bibname{References} 
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\include{chapter1_MWE}
\end{document}
```

Chapter 1 (chapter1_MWE)

```
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\label{sec:chapter1}
The text goes here.\cite{winzeler2008malaria}
Then more text.\cite{hall2005comprehensive}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{./Bibliographies/chapter1_MWE}
```

Bibliography (chapter1_MWE)

```
@article{winzeler2008malaria,
  title={Malaria},
  author={Winzeler, Elizabeth Ann},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={455},
  number={7214},
  pages={751--756},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{hall2005comprehensive,
  title={A comprehensive survey},
  author={Hall, Neil, and Karras, Marianna and Raine, Ja Dale and Carlton, Jane M and Kooij, Taco WA and Berriman, Matthew and Florens, Laurence and Janssen, Christoph S and Pain, Arnab and Christophides, Georges K, and James, K and Trueman, H E and Mendoza Jac and Bidwell, Shelby L and Rajandream, M-A and Carucci, Dan J and Yates, John R III and Kafatos, F C and Janse, C J and Barrell, B and Turner, M R and Waters, Andre P and Sinden, Rob E},
  journal={Science},
  volume={307},
  number={5706},
  pages={82--86},
  year={2005},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

This doesn't exactly put out what my main working file does, but it is close enough.

Comment: Saying that nothing is working doesn't help to reproduce your situation. Can you please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to better understand what your problem is?

Comment: @karlkoeller, I pared down my main file - this doesn't exactly have the right output, but it is close.  Anyway, I want to manipulate the bibliography output.

Comment: I doubt I will be able to help, but perhaps someone will do if you specify what you want to achieve with your code... I mean, what don't you like in the result?